# Suppose that is $f$ is a measurable function, and $g$ differs with $f$ only by a measure zero set, is $g$ measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Suppose that is $f$ is a measurable function, and $g$ differs with $f$ only by a measure zero set, is  $g$ measurable? I do not think this is necessarily right, but is there any counter example?

Comment: Are you talking about measurabilty on $\Bbb R^n$ with the usual measurable structure, or about abstract measurable spaces?

Comment: I am trying to think of an abstract measurable space, but will the conclusion differ under different situations?

Comment: I was just confused by your chosen tag - "real-analysis". I have changed it to suit your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

1. The sum of two measurable functions is measurable.
2. For any $E$, either $\{x: f(x)-g(x) \in E\}$ or its complement has measure $0$.

Comment: I am sorry but I am a little confused with your second hint.

Comment: I see. So the answer for the question should be yes, right?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether your measure is complete. Consider, for example, Lebesgue measure on the Borel subsets of the unit interval $[0,1]$. Let $f(x)=x$ for $x\in[0,1]$. Let $K\subset[0,1]$ denote the Cantor set. Choose a  non-Borel-measurable subset $B$ of $K$. Define $g(x)=f(x)$ for $x\in [0,1]\setminus K$ and $g(x) =2+1_B(x)$ for $x\in K$. Then $\{x:f(x)\not=g(x)\}=K$ is a measurable set of measure $0$, but $g^{-1}(\{3\})=B$, so $g$ is not (Borel) measurable.